# How to get the url's value of $http.get() to use inside the function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I parsed three different web services using AngularJS: Here's my code:

```
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {        
function getLists() {
var tab = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
var list = [];
for(i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    $http.get(tab[i]) 
    .then(function(res) {
        res.data.error='';
        list.push(res.data);
    }).catch(function (res) {
res.data.error='file not found';
});
}
return list;
}

return {
getLists: getLists
};
]);
```

In an html page I have to show the data found in Json files
`<tr ng-repeat="d in list" ng-show="d.error == ''">
    <td>{{d.nm}}</td>
    <td>{{d.cty}}</td>

    <td>{{d.hse}}</td>
    <td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr> 
<tr ng-repeat="d in list"ng-show="d.error != ''">
  <td>File not found</td></tr>`

So if the URL is not found or there is an error I should show a line where I put error. 
What I want now is tp specify the Url not found. For example if url1 is not found, I want to put a message url1+" is not found"
I tried to do this in my factory

```
res.data.error= tab[i]+' file not found';
```

and in my html :

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list"ng-show="d.error != ''">
  <td>{{d.error}}</td></tr>
```

but nothing appeared and when I used an alert to debug

```
alert(tab[i]+' file not found');
```

I got 'undefined file not found'.
Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: AngularJS is asynchronous by default. You can't just return an array  in the method `getLists()`, it will never work. Instead, you have to use callbacks. [Here is a good article](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/) explaining about it. Good luck!

Comment: Thankj you @ShadowWizard that helped me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the response object, `res.config.url` contains the url which was hit.
But then, as the url did not exist, the `.catch block` will be executed and not `.then block`

```
$http.get(tab[i]) 
.catch(function(res) {
   res.data = { error : res.config.url +' file not found' };
})
```

also, you will have to make the calling code use it asynchronously, right now you are trying to access in synchronous way, which will never work...